# How to give a block a floating name without using armour stands or mobs

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm wondering how I would give a block a floating name tag, I've used mobs and armour stands but they're "meh" in the sense of full efficency

However, if I used `/give structure_block` the structure block by default has a floating name tag, and upon killing all entities in the game, that block doesn't disappear (meaning it's not an entity).

So is there a way to replicate this with other blocks? (i.e. give other blocks a floating name tag above it).

I would like to achieve this in vanilla, no mods, no plugins

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this yourself? Arqade works better when askers show effort to solve their own problems; we see that you have a problem you've worked on, and answerers respond to that. You also get a more specific answer that's tailored exactly to the part you're stuck, and Arqade gets a very specific question. Everybody wins!

Comment: Hey @Frank if you re-read the question you will see I tried the only two current ways possible known on arqade i.e. using the search feature. If you read the question properly it saves wasting a comment, then a reply to be made. If you read questions properly it saves hassle and everybody wins! :)

Answer (score 1):

Nope. Just a thing structure blocks do, we have no control over that with commands.

Comment: ... meaning that the armor stand thing is already the best way.

Comment: @Fabian incorrect, the way it is set, there must be functionallity at a code level to assign a floating name tag as that block has one assigned if you get where I'm coming from

Comment: @Quiet If it's hardcoded for structure blocks there is no other way. You can't override the game with commands, unless you mod it.

Comment: @dly doesn't matter dude I got it with data tags, in vanilla, it's all good, one of the data tags within blockstate is used to give any block a floating name, i.e. how they did it with structure_block, well thats 15 hours of data mining I'll never get back haha, it was added in a 1.12.2 snapshot under a hidden field

Comment: @Quiet Sure, care to show us then? I doubt it, because you're talking out of your ass <3.

Comment: @Pepijn Of course man, I'm really not talking out my ass, you got a discord I can join and I'll paste the code out or you can look at my command log book in the server